# Propagation of Filter context when using DAX

Tags: excel, dax

I understand that fitlercontext propagates from one table to another table along relationships and that it only propagates from the one side to the many side.

I can't see why DAX would not propogate it's fitlers from the many to the one side.  I've been reading the book from http://www.daxpatterns.com/ and other DAX books (by the same well known authors) and I just don't get why it would need to work like this.

See my example here: 
[My OneNote page](https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx/Documents/My%20Training/Train%20SQL%20Server%20and%20BI?cid=53b31f7a44698440&id=documents?&wd=target%28DAX%20Patterns.one%7c7563071D-BF5E-4918-B7BB-BFB1DA3A0F05%2fPropagation%20of%20Filter%20Context%7cBF2FADFB-C8E7-4048-95A4-DD9495ADF358%2f%29)

This is very counter intuitive for me, and it makes me very uncomfortable.  If I had written a SQL statement selecting data from tables that were related with a variety of relationships, any "filters" (ie WHERE clauses) on any of the tables reduces down the dataset that was created through including all the joined tables in the tables used.  (ie the filters propagate)

I'm quite new to DAX so may be I just need to keep reading.  However, in my example pivot table above, as a user of the data model, I would have really have liked to have been able to get data from the DimTime table.

If you have any useful thoughts I would very much appreciate it if you could share them!

For what it's worth, if I were using excel 2007 (ie pre powerpivot) and creating a "data model" in excel ranges.  I would have a long FactInternetSales range.  Say I add columns to this table using VLOOKUP to get data from two other short lookup tables which have a MANY TO ONE relationship with the current table.  I can add filters to columns from all three tables AND THE FILTER CONTEXT PROPAGATES!

Thanks in advance, 
Harvey

Comment: If it makes you feel any better bi-directional relationships are coming in the Power BI designer, but you would have to have Power BI and use the designer to create your model rather than Excel. https://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2015/01/01/bidirectional-relationships-and-many-to-many-in-the-power-bi-designer/

Comment: I read the link. I'm glad it's seen as an issue that needs addressing. Cripes, without the many to many support it's likely to be a real bugger in Excel. If you don't want to use DAX to achieve the many2many table join, you could do this:  If three tables have a many2one2many relationship you'd need to create a new "excel data model table" based on a view that includes two of the "excel data model tables" and use that in place of two tables in the "one2many2one" in effect giving you a simple "one2many" that Excel can cope with....  Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Please make your question self-contained by including everything necessary to understanding your question in the post itself. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.